# Union Query In Separate Databases

Tags: ms-access, union-all

I have 2 databases.  In database1, I want to run a query from database2 and `UNION ALL` the results.  This is the syntax I tried, but I get an error of

```
Syntax error in from clause
```

Here is the syntax I tried --- where is my error?

```
SELECT * FROM query1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM query1 IN C:\Database\production.mdb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes around the path of the external database.

I would also use aliases to distinguish between the 2 instances of *query1*.

```sql
SELECT q1Local.* FROM query1 AS q1Local
UNION ALL
SELECT q1Remote.* FROM query1 AS q1Remote IN 'C:\Database\production.mdb'
```